# Getting results from Hbase table using "like" like functionality

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to get all row keys which match a particular pattern from Hbase table. The rowkey are present in a particular format as abc:def:ghi.
I am trying to write a java code which would get me all row keys starting with "abc". If any one can give me some idea , by using filter or any other method we can obtain the same . That would be very grateful.

Thanks 
Ashit

Comment: Got the answer ... we can use prefix filter to do the same in java api .

Comment: This looks like a good case to use a range scan. Here are some Java examples: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan.

Comment: Thanks @HellmarBecker for the current scenario prefix filter solves my problem.